# How to implement a ScanAsync operator with async accumulator in Rx.Net?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive, state-machine, rx.net

The `Scan` Operator in Rx.Net has signature:

```cs
public static IObservable<TAccumulate> Scan<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator);
```

The accumulator is

```cs
Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator
```

While trying to implement a state machine model with async state transition, I found a `ScanAsync` operator with following signature would be helpful.

```cs
public static IObservable<TAccumulate> Scan<TSource, TAccumulate>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, Task<TAccumulate>> accumulator);
```

The accumulator has signature

```cs
Func<TAccumulate, TSource, Task<TAccumulate>> accumulator
```

Ideal application code would be something like this (similar to normal `Scan` operator, with difference on using async accumulator).

```cs
IObservable<TEvent> events;
IObservable<State> states = events.ScanAsync(
    initialState, 
    async (previousState, evt) => {
        var newState = await transitionAsync(previousState, evt);
        return newState;
    });
```

It seems MS is developing [AsyncRx.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/tree/master/AsyncRx.NET), however it is [not released yet(no schedule)](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1118).

---

Related things:

If modeling async state machine by `BehaviourSubject` for states, and subscribe events observable, like the following code

```cs
IObservable<TEvent> events;
BehaviourSubject<State> states = new BehaviourSubject<State>(initialState);
events.Subscribe(async e => {
    var newState = await transition(states.Value, e);
    states.OnNext(newState);
})
```

I guess there might be race conditions in certain cases.

I've tried implementing it with

```cs
IObservable<TS> ScanAsync<TS, TE>(
IObservable<TE> source,
Func<TS, TE, Task<TS>> reducer,
TS initialState)
{
    var states = from m in source.Take(1)
                    from nextState in reducer(initialState, m).ToObservable()
                    from s in ScanAsync(source.Skip(1), reducer, nextState)
                    select s;
    return Observable.Return(initialState).Concat(states);
}
```

However it sometimes works, some times it just blocked, and I have no idea what's causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Scan` operator to create an intermediate `IObservable<Task<TAccumulate>>`, which can then be flattened by using the `Concat` operator:

```
public static IObservable<TAccumulate> Scan<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, Task<TAccumulate>> accumulator)
{
    return source.Scan(Task.FromResult(seed), async (previousTask, item) =>
    {
        return await accumulator(await previousTask, item);
    }).Concat();
}
```

The implementation above uses the `Concat` overload that accepts an observable of tasks, instead of a nested observable:

```
// Concatenates all task results, as long as the previous task terminated successfully.
public static IObservable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(
    this IObservable<Task<TSource>> sources);
```